# Not able to click on second row of datepicker while adding data in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am generating rows on click of `.add` class. SO when I generate 3 rows, and I start adding data for the first row in datepicker. It gives me to add the date.

> But when I go and set date for second row, the mouse takes me to the first `fromdate` text control.

same thing is happening for `todate` also. Even I generate different ID;s for each row still i am unable to add the date for second and third row.

Below is my html

```
<tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="row noPadding vendorForm">
                                    <div class="vendorDaterow">
                                        <div class="vendorName" id="dvVendorNameData">
                                            <label>SP Vender Name</label><span><input type="text" name="nmVendorData" id="txtVendorName" /></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="vendorFromDate">
                                            <label>From Date</label><span class="datepicker"><input type="text" name="spFromDate" id="spFromDate1" class="dateClass" /><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="vendorToDate">
                                            <label>To Date</label><span class="datepicker"><input type="text" name="spToDate" id="spToDate1" class="dateClass" /><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="add">
                                        <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <i class="max">(Maximum 5 Vendors)</i>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5xvzztsg/) for generated HTML

Kindly suggest where I am wrong and I am unable to add date for second and third row

Answer (score 0):

Check this Code it will working datepicker for cloned element,hasDatepicker class remove for datepicker input after adding clone element to tr and apply  $('.dateClass').datepicker({ dateFormat: "m/d/yy" }); so datepicker working properly

```js
$('.dateClass').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: "m/d/yy"
});
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var toAddCloneCount = 2;

    $('.add').on('click', function () {
        var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var $tr2 = $tr.clone(true, true);
        $tr2.find(".vendorName").children('label').remove();
        $tr2.find(".add").children().remove();
        $tr2.find(".vendorFromDate").children('label').remove();
        $tr2.find(".vendorToDate").children('label').remove();
        $tr2.find('#txtVendorName').prop('id', 'txtVendorName' + toAddCloneCount);
        $tr2.find('#spFromDate1').prop('id', 'spFromDate' + toAddCloneCount);
        $tr2.find('#spToDate1').prop('id', 'spToDate' + toAddCloneCount++);
               
        $tr2.insertAfter($tr);
         $('.dateClass').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker();
    });
       });
```

```css
#ui-datepicker-div { font-size: 12px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<table>
<tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="row noPadding vendorForm">
                                        <div class="vendorDaterow">
                                            <div class="vendorName" id="dvVendorNameData">
                                                <label>SP Vender Name</label><span><input type="text" name="nmVendorData" id="txtVendorName"></span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="vendorFromDate">
                                                <label>From Date</label><span class="datepicker"><input type="text" name="spFromDate1" id="spFromDate1" class="dateClass "><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="vendorToDate">
                                                <label>To Date</label><span class="datepicker"><input type="text" name="spToDate" id="spToDate1" class="dateClass "><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="add">
                                            <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <i class="max">(Maximum 5 Vendors)</i>

                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hey will check on Monday as I have to leave today early. Sorry for keep u waiting. Will update u

Comment: @VVVV It's Okey

Comment: @VVVV i am happy to help you,Mate

Comment: hi bro, I will connect to u in next 5 mins. if possible come on chat